# Text input with Tensorflow

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network, tensorflow-datasets

I am playing with Tensorflow and trying to build a RNN language model.
I am struggling with how to read raw text input file.

[Tensorflow guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/datasets) mentioned a few approaches, including:

1. `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices()` - which assumes my data is available in memory (np.array？)
2. `tf.data.TFRecordDataset` (no idea how to use this)
3. `tf.data.TextLineDataset` (what's the difference with 2? the API page are almost identical)

Confused with 2 and 3, I can only try approach 1, but facing the following issues:

1. what if my data is too big to fit in memory?
2. TF requires a fix-length, padded format, how do I do it? - 
   Do I:
   Decide on a fix-length value (e.g. 30),
   read each line into a list, truncate the list to 30 if it is longer 
   then 30, 
   fill '0's to to make each line at least 30 long,
   append the list to a numpy array/matrix ?

I am sure these are such common problems that tensorflow much have provided built-in functions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data is in text files (csv, tsv or just a collection of lines), the best way is to process it is with [`tf.data.TextLineDataset`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/TextLineDataset); [`tf.data.TFRecordDataset`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/TFRecordDataset) has a similar API, but it's for `TFRecord` binary format (checkout [this nice post](https://planspace.org/20170323-tfrecords_for_humans/) if you want some details).

A good example of text line processing via dataset API is [TensorFlow Wide & Deep Learning Tutorial](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/docs_src/tutorials/wide_and_deep.md) (the code is [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/official/wide_deep/)). Here's the input function used there:

```py
def input_fn(data_file, num_epochs, shuffle, batch_size):
  """Generate an input function for the Estimator."""
  assert tf.gfile.Exists(data_file), (
      '%s not found. Please make sure you have either run data_download.py or '
      'set both arguments --train_data and --test_data.' % data_file)

  def parse_csv(value):
    print('Parsing', data_file)
    columns = tf.decode_csv(value, record_defaults=_CSV_COLUMN_DEFAULTS)
    features = dict(zip(_CSV_COLUMNS, columns))
    labels = features.pop('income_bracket')
    return features, tf.equal(labels, '>50K')

  # Extract lines from input files using the Dataset API.
  dataset = tf.data.TextLineDataset(data_file)

  if shuffle:
    dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=_NUM_EXAMPLES['train'])

  dataset = dataset.map(parse_csv, num_parallel_calls=5)

  # We call repeat after shuffling, rather than before, to prevent separate
  # epochs from blending together.
  dataset = dataset.repeat(num_epochs)
  dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)

  iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
  features, labels = iterator.get_next()
  return features, labels
```

Here's what's going on in this snippet:

- `tf.data.TextLineDataset(data_file)` line creates a [`Dataset`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset) object, assigned to `dataset`. It is a wrapper, not the contents holder, so the data is *never* read entirely into memory.
- `Dataset` API allows to pre-process the data, e.g. with `shuffle`, `map`, `batch` and other methods. Note that API is functional, meaning that no data is processed when you call `Dataset` methods, they just define what transformations will be performed with tensors when the session actually starts and an iterator is evaluated (see below).
- Finally, `dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()` returns an iterator tensor, from which one can read the values. You can evaluate `features` and `labels` and they will get the values of the data batches after transformation.
- Also note that if you train your model on a GPU, the data will be streamed to the device directly, without intermediate stop in a client (python script itself).

Depending on your particular format, you won't probably need to parse the csv columns and simply read lines one by one.

---

**Suggested reading**: [Importing Data](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/datasets) guide.